# two text button inside a container outline

Tags: flutter, uibutton

[example im trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NCE7.png)

ive been try to replicate this in flutter where its two text buttons in a container with a check mark when clicked but ive been having trouble inserting the second button

```
  Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 3.0),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(
                      5.0) //                 <--- border radius here
                  ),
            ),
            //
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                child: TextButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                      overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                        if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed))
                          return Colors.blue;
                        return null;
                      }),
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                          RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)))),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text('TextButton with custom overlay colors'),
                )),
          ),
```

Comment: Could you reformat this so it's easier to read the code. Use ``` code here ``` format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this build method :

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Center(
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 3.0),
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular( 5.0) ), ),
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                child: TextButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                      overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>( (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                        if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
                          return Colors.blue;
                        }
                        return Colors.red;
                      }),
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>( RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)))),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text('TextButton with custom overlay colors'),
                )
            ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                child: TextButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                      overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>( (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                        if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
                          return Colors.blue;
                        }
                        return Colors.red;
                      }),
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>( RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)))),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text('TextButton with custom overlay colors'),
                )
            )
              ]
          ),
        ),
    ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: much appreciate the help how would you do the check mark on the button aligned that way

Comment: you are welcome bro , you can add a prefix attribute to the button and put the widget you want to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Column() widget as your container's child. It will allow you to stack two buttons on top of each other.